# Android project for displaing driving routes not working

Tags: java, android, google-maps, driving-directions

I am developing an android app for displaying driving routes between 2 points by following this tutorial-
http://asmncl.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/android-draw-route-map-between-two.html
, but my app is stopping after I run it.
I am not using kml,as I know kml is no longer supported by Google.
But, when I run this code, its stopping.
Can someone tell me, what could be the reason?

**EDIT** It turns out that I didnot included the google map library in my androidmanfest.xml.
Now, its not showing any error, but after installing it on the phone its crashing.
Can anyone tell me, why?

Thanks

**RoutePath-Main Activity**

```
public class RoutePath extends MapActivity { 

        MapView mapView;
        private RoutePath _activity;
        GeoPoint srcGeoPoint,destGeoPoint;
        private static List<Overlay> mOverlays;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SharedData data = SharedData.getInstance();
            mapView = new MapView(this,data.getAPIKEY());
            mapView.setClickable(true);        
            setContentView(mapView); 
            _activity = this;
            double src_lat = data.getSrc_lat();
            double src_long = data.getSrc_lng();
            double dest_lat = data.getDest_lat();
            double dest_long = data.getDest_lng();


            if(src_lat == -1 || src_long == -1 || dest_lat == -1 || dest_long == -1){
                showAlert("Please enter source and destination points");
            }else{

                srcGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (src_lat * 1E6),(int) (src_long * 1E6)); 
                destGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (dest_lat * 1E6),(int) (dest_long * 1E6)); 

                List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                Drawable srcdrawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_green);
                CustomItemizedOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(srcdrawable);
                //CustomItemizedOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(getDrawable("com/agarwal/route/pin_green.png"));
                OverlayItem srcoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(srcGeoPoint, "Hello!", "This is your Location.");

                Drawable destdrawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_red);
                CustomItemizedOverlay  destitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay( destdrawable );
               // CustomItemizedOverlay destitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(getDrawable("com/agarwal/route/pin_red.png"));
                OverlayItem destoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(destGeoPoint, "Hello!", "This is dest Location.");

                srcitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(srcoverlayitem);
                destitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(destoverlayitem);

                mapOverlays.add(srcitemizedOverlay);
                mapOverlays.add(destitemizedOverlay);

                connectAsyncTask _connectAsyncTask = new connectAsyncTask();
                _connectAsyncTask.execute();        
                mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
                mOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                mapView.getController().animateTo(srcGeoPoint); 
                mapView.getController().setZoom(12); 
                //SharedData data = SharedData.getInstance();
                data.setAPIKEY("APIKEY");
                data.setSrc_lat(17);
                data.setSrc_lng(78);
                data.setDest_lat(18);
                data.setDest_lng(77);
                startActivity(new Intent(RoutePath.this,RoutePath.class));

            } 
        }
        @Override 
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            return false; 
        } 

        private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
            private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(_activity);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                fetchData();
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);            
                if(doc!=null){
                    Overlay ol = new MyOverlay(_activity,srcGeoPoint,srcGeoPoint,1);
                    mOverlays.add(ol);
                    NodeList _nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("status");
                    Node node1 = _nodelist.item(0);
                    String _status1  = node1.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                    if(_status1.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
                        NodeList _nodelist_path = doc.getElementsByTagName("overview_polyline");
                        Node node_path = _nodelist_path.item(0);
                        Element _status_path = (Element)node_path;
                        NodeList _nodelist_destination_path = _status_path.getElementsByTagName("points");
                        Node _nodelist_dest = _nodelist_destination_path.item(0);
                        String _path  = _nodelist_dest.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                        List<GeoPoint> _geopoints = decodePoly(_path);
                        GeoPoint gp1; 
                        GeoPoint gp2; 
                        gp2 = _geopoints.get(0);
                        Log.d("_geopoints","::"+_geopoints.size());
                        for(int i=1;i<_geopoints.size();i++) // the last one would be crash 
                        { 

                            gp1 = gp2;
                            gp2 = _geopoints.get(i);
                            Overlay ol1 = new MyOverlay(gp1,gp2,2,Color.BLUE);
                            mOverlays.add(ol1);
                        } 
                        Overlay ol2 = new MyOverlay(_activity,destGeoPoint,destGeoPoint,3);
                        mOverlays.add(ol2);

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }else{
                        showAlert("Unable to find the route");
                    }

                    Overlay ol2 = new MyOverlay(_activity,destGeoPoint,destGeoPoint,3);
                    mOverlays.add(ol2);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    mapView.scrollBy(-1,-1);
                    mapView.scrollBy(1,1);
                }else{
                    showAlert("Unable to find the route");
                }

            }

        }
        Document doc = null;
        private void fetchData()
        {
            StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
            urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=");
            urlString.append( Double.toString((double)srcGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 )); 
            urlString.append(","); 
            urlString.append( Double.toString((double)srcGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 )); 
            urlString.append("&destination=");//to 
            urlString.append( Double.toString((double)destGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 )); 
            urlString.append(","); 
            urlString.append( Double.toString((double)destGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 )); 
            urlString.append("&sensor=true&mode=driving");     
            Log.d("url","::"+urlString.toString());
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null; 
            URL url = null; 
            try 
            { 
                url = new URL(urlString.toString()); 
                urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); 
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); 
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true); 
                urlConnection.connect(); 
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                doc = (Document) db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());//Util.XMLfromString(response);
            }catch (MalformedURLException e){ 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }catch (IOException e){ 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }catch (ParserConfigurationException e){ 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
            catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        private List<GeoPoint> decodePoly(String encoded) {

            List<GeoPoint> poly = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
            int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
            int lat = 0, lng = 0;

            while (index < len) {
                int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
                do {
                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                    shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lat += dlat;

                shift = 0;
                result = 0;
                do {
                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                    shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lng += dlng;

                GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (((double) lat / 1E5) * 1E6),
                        (int) (((double) lng / 1E5) * 1E6));
                poly.add(p);
            }

            return poly;
        }
        private void showAlert(String message){
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(_activity);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setMessage(message);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
        private Drawable getDrawable(String fileName){
            return Drawable.createFromStream(_activity.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName), "pin");
        }

    }
```

I created 3 more classes -SharedData.java, CustomItemizedOverlay.java , MyOverrlay.java.
I am passing my API_KEY through SharedData.java.

**Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
     android:id="@+id/mapid"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:apiKey="APIKEY"
     />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            tools:context=".RoutePath" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.path"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
            <activity
                android:name=".RoutePath"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_path" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: you did not add `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>` in `application` tag.

Answer (score 0):

you should add your Google Map Api Key , the Debug One , in your MapView in your Layout ...

Comment: I have added my APIKEY in my project, but the app is closing down after starting it.It's not displaying anything.

Comment: Dude , you are Wrong here i think setContentView(mapView); , MapView is a View In a Layout ,like a Button or ImageView , so setContentView(R.layout.main); right ?